# Firebase chat backup/export like whatsapp in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]i implemented a chat app in swift using firebase real time db, there user can send images, emojis and Text.Now i have a requirement of export chat or get the conversation's backup with media and text as per whatsApp.help me to solving it out.

Answer (score 1):

While Firebase offers a backup for the Realtime Database, this doesn't fit your needs here, since you'll want a per-user export of the data.

Since this is specific to your application, you will have to code it yourself, just like the good folks at WhatsApp have probably done. It should be a matter of iterating over all data sources for the user, getting the data through the relevant API (that you're already using to display that data), and then writing to a local file). You can do this either client-side in your Swift code, or server-side on a server you already may have, or using Cloud Functions.

If you're looking for some inspiration for the latter, there is a [sample repository that shows how to clean up a user's data](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/user-data-protection), based on a set of wipe-out rules. You'll need to significantly modify this example though, so I'm not convinced this will be less work than rolling your own from scratch.

Comment: i need like the attached image, we can say that a backup of chat or export of chat into a text file

Comment: Since this is specific to your application, you will have to code it yourself. If you have tried something and got stuck, we can typically help you if you post the [minimum, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: actually i don't have any idea how to start it

Comment: If you implemented the chat app on Firebase, getting the same data for export should not be much different.